# Need to correct my mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, mysqli

I am using mysqli in PHP and trying to get data from database to get logged in into system. When I use phpmyadmin to execute my query, I get perfect result. But when I try to get it from php script, I get a prob. My php script is below

```
if(isset($login)){


$email = @$db->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['loginid']));
$username = @$db->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['loginid']));
$pass1 = @$db->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['loginpass']));

$blah = new Encryption();
$pass = $blah->encode($pass1);


    if($db->query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE BINARY `uname` = '$username' AND `pass` = '$pass'")){
    $errors[] = 'Logged in by username';
    }
    else if($db->query("SELECT `uid` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$username' AND `pass` = '$pass'")){
    $errors[] = 'Logged in by email';
    }   

}
```

Now the thing is that my username is 'abc', email is 'abc@abc.com' and password is 'qazwsx' in encrypted. the second username is 'xyz', email is 'xyz@xyz.com' and password is 'abcdef' and but it is not checking uname and pass both at once or email and pass both at once. If I enter '1' or anything with 'qazwsx' password, it shows me you are 'logged in by username' means it is checking only password.

And to see result, I've used these codes,

```
if($errors){
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($errors as $error){
            echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
} 

else if ($loginform){
    echo $loginform;
    }
```

I don't know what to do. Please help me guyz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding 0 rows is not an error.  A query can find nothing and still return success.

You want to check after the query returns and make sure the result contains at least one row.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT....");
if ($result and $result->num_rows) {
    # query found a matching user
}
```

Comment: can you suggest me what code should I use? Can you edit my codes?

Comment: Thanx, it worked for username, but I still cannot login with email id. :'(

Comment: If you've done the same thing for both, then you're running up against a whole different problem.  What does the value in your DB look like, and what does the value you use in your query look like after you escape it?

Comment: Oh, and i guess i should ask...did you intend that the username and email both come from `$_POST['loginid']`?

Comment: Ya, email n username both comes from loginid. but now, its working with email... :D thanks for helping me... ;)